# UI-Router : Prevent access to parent state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I am moving to `UI-Router` as my App router. I want to have nested state as below:

```
$stateProvider
.state('app', {
      url: '/app',
      template: ' <div ui-view></div>',
      authenticate: true
    })
.state('app.state1', {
      url: '/state1',
      templateUrl: 'app/state1.html',
      controller: 'State1Ctrl',
      controllerAs: 'state1',
      authenticate: true
    })
.state('app.state2', {
      url: '/state2',
      templateUrl: 'app/state2.html',
      controller: 'State2Ctrl',
      authenticate: true
    })
```

My `$state` called `app` is the parent of others. It only consists of a `<div ui-view></div>` template. It should not be accessible directly. I mean if a user enters  `/app` in the URL, they should be redirected  to `app.state1``

How can I prevent my users of doing this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/TZGGWhTIO0yeJ7ApHAwf?p=preview)

Make your state **`abstract`**:

```
  .state('app', {
      url: '/app',
      abstract: true, // here
      template: ' <div ui-view></div>',
      authenticate: true
    })
```

And add some default redirections:

```
  $urlRouterProvider.when('/app', '/app/state1');
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/state1');
```

The first 2 links below will redirect to 'app.state1'

```
<a href="#/app"> // will be redirected to state1
<a href="#/app/state1">
<a href="#/app/state2">
```

The [doc about $stateProvider](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider):

> **`abstract`** *(optional)* `boolean`
>
> An abstract state will never be directly activated, but can provide inherited properties to its common children states.

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TZGGWhTIO0yeJ7ApHAwf?p=preview)

Comment: Great! Enjoy powerful UI-Router ;)